# Conseguir link redirecionado internamente no aplicativo android

Tags: java, android, conexão, internet

Aloha

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Android para fazer login automático na rede wifi, mas encontrei uma barreira. No aplicativo, quando o usuário clica no botão "Logar", preciso internamente acessar algum endereço que será redirecionado link correto.

**Vou descrever a situação**

- Nesta rede wifi, quando o usuário vai fazer o login uma url único é gerado para o usuário. Aquela url só pode ser acessada naquele momento, e em qualquer outra requisição uma nova url é gerada. Isso tudo utilizando tokens aleatórios.
- Não existe uma url única que, quando acessada, abre a página de login.

**Minha ideia inicial**

Quando o Android se depara com a necessidade de efetuar login na rede, ele abre a url "http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204".
Assim, imaginei se pudesse ter uma forma de, quando o usuário clica em *Logar*, abrir internamente este link (sem que apareça para o usuário), pegue o link único com o token e retorne essa url, para que seja utilizado para fazer o login.

Não posso afirmar que isso funcionará, mas é minha melhor ideia até o momento. Estou aberto a novas ideias, claro, mas se alguém tiver uma noção de como fazer isso e puder me fornecer um código fonte para realizar a função, seria excelente.

Precisando de mais informações, favor pedir.